# Compute the number of seconds to a specific time in a specific Time Zone

Tags: ruby, time

I want to trigger a notification for all my users at a specific time in their time zone. I want to compute the delay the server should wait before firing the notification. I can compute the time at the users Time Zone using Time.now.in_time_zone(person.time_zone)

I can strip out the hours, minutes and seconds from that time and find out the seconds remaining to the specific time. However, I was wondering if there's a more elegant method where I could set 9:00 AM on today and tomorrow in a timezone and compare it with Time.now.in_time_zone(person.time_zone) and just find out the number of seconds using arithmetic operations in the ruby Time Class.

Or in short my question is: (was: before the downvote!)

How do I compute the number of seconds to the next 9:00 AM in New York?

Comment: You might get some value for https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

```
next9am = Time.now.in_time_zone(person.time_zone).seconds_until_end_of_day + 3600 * 9 
next9am -=  24 * 60 * 60 if Time.now.in_time_zone(person.time_zone).hour < 9
```

Comment: That is buggy. what if it is 6:00 AM local time?

Comment: don't think this is a valid comparison :Time.now.in_time_zone(person.time_zone) < 9

Does that work on the console?

Answer (score 0):

```
NOTIFICATION_HOUR = 9
local_time = Time.now.in_time_zone(person.time_zone)
desired_time = local_time.hour >= NOTIFICATION_HOUR ? local_time + 1.day : local_time
desired_time = Time.new(desired_time.year, desired_time.month, desired_time.day, NOTIFICATION_HOUR, 0, 0, desired_time.utc_offset)
return desired_time - local_time
```